# Hiding/showing QgsVectorLayer using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, visibility, qgsvectorlayer

Once created a layer, how can I hide/show it? I can enable/disable the rendering of a specific layer by selecting the checkbox through QGIS, but I need to do it programmatically with PyQGIS.

How can I show/hide(not remove) a label from Python code?

I'm looking for something like:

```py
aLayer = self.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), layerName, self.dbConn.getProviderName())
aLayer.Hide()
....
aLayer.Show()
```

Comment: I'm glad you changed the variable name `vl` (from the similar code sample in an earlier question) to `aLayer`. It's easy to confuse the lowercase letter `l` with the digit `1`.

Comment: @andytilia: you are right. I edited the old questions too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### For QGIS 2 versions

One can control the layer visibility through the legend object. Here it is, using your sample code above:

```py
aLayer = self.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), layerName, self.dbConn.getProviderName())

legend = self.legendInterface()  # access the legend
legend.setLayerVisible(aLayer, False)  # hide the layer
# do something else
legend.setLayerVisible(aLayer, True)  # show the layer

# maybe later I want to check if the layer is visible
print legend.isLayerVisible(aLayer)
```

For more details, see the documentation for `legendInterface`: https://api.qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsLegendInterface.html

Answer (score 1):

### For QGIS 3 versions

It can be achieved either

#### since QGIS 3.10

or the [`setLayerVisible()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeView.html#a8f1488f18e32f16f4bc8c46bd2053f0e) method of the `QgsLayerTreeView` class:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()
view = iface.layerTreeView()

view.setLayerVisible(layer, False)
```

#### since QGIS 3.0

through the [`setItemVisibilityChecked()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeNode.html#ad6c4e357cbf618dbe00fe5e7d44276e8) method, that belongs to the `QgsLayerTreeNode` class:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer = iface.activeLayer()

node = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer.id())

if node.isVisible():
  node.setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```

---

**References:**

- [Setting layer visibility with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119280/setting-layer-visibility-with-pyqgis)
- [Applying setVisible in PyQGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279451/applying-setvisible-in-pyqgis-3)
- [Deselecting layer using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/435787/deselecting-layer-using-pyqgis)
- [qgis/QGIS/tests/src/python
  /test_qgslayertreeview.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgslayertreeview.py)