# Setting layer visibility with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, visibility, qgsvectorlayer

Im having a problem toggling the visibility of map layers in PyQGIS (2.4). I have a simple interface, just the map canvas, no legend, and a radio button that toggles between two raster layers.

Layers are initialized like this:

```py
lyr = QgsRasterLayer(os.getcwd() + '/data/rasters/dof/dof.vrt', 'Ortophoto')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr, False)
ml = QgsMapCanvasLayer(lyr)
ml.setVisible(False)
    
lyr2 = QgsRasterLayer(os.getcwd() + '/data/rasters/chm/chm.vrt', 'Chm')        
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr2, False)
ml2 = QgsMapCanvasLayer(lyr2)
ml2.setVisible(True)
```

When I want to toggle their visibility I do:

```py
ml.setVisible(True)
ml2.setVisible(False)
```

But unfortunately, the rendering on the map canvas stays the same.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment (QGIS 2.x) (and I know it's a bit gross) but you also have to update the layer set on the canvas to update the layer state change

```
canvas.setLayerSet([ml2, ml])
```

This will also control the render order. `m1` will reneder first then `ml2` on top of it.

Comment: THIS is the correct answer. GIS.SE saves the day once more ;>

Answer (score 17):

For QGIS 3, you have to use:

```py
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer_id).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```

or to be safe

```py
node = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer_id)
if node:
  node.setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```

Reading the [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsLayerTreeGroup.html#qgis.core.QgsLayerTreeGroup.findLayer), `findLayer` accepts both the layer itself and the layer ID as a string.

Comment: Is it possible to use a variable instead of the layer name in 'layer.id()' ?

Comment: yes, I update the code and added a pointer to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 2, You have to refresh the mapCanvas as well:

```
 ml.setVisible(True)
 ml2.setVisible(False)

 qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

After this the map Canvas will redraw and you can see the changes.

Normally you should see changes when you zoom in and out to force a refresh of the mapCanvas manually.

To set the layer visibility you can use this:

```
 qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(m1, False)
 qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(m12, True)
```

I think mapCanvas doesn't have a method to set teh layer visibility. A setLayerVisibility can only be found in the QgsLegendInterface:

http://qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendInterface.html#ae77bf61a8c81bee9f861c6f7d7c7d8cf

If this doesn't work you can also change the transparency of a raster layer with `QgsRasterTransparency.TransparentSingleValuePixel()` like in this post

[How do I set layer transparency in QGIS 2.0 with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77391/how-do-i-set-layer-transparency-in-qgis-2-0-with-python)

Comment: Doesn't work.I tried zooming in/out anyway.

Comment: I refreshed the map canvas instance directly self.ui.map.refresh()

Comment: Must be something else in my code then. It is a helpful if i know this is the way to do it ;>

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer... in 2.4 qgis.utils no longer exists. How do you access iface.legenInterface()?

Comment: I use Qgis2.4 and i use for example to get the active layer in a plugin `layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()` or import qgis.utils

Comment: hmm, im using the api as a standalone application setup, import qgis.utils evaluates and the program exits.