# Set layer visibility using QgsMapCanvasLayer in QGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

How should one migrate code using `QgsMapCanvasLayer` to set layer visibility?

The [QGIS3 API break page](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html) didn't say that `QgsMapCanvasLayer` is removed or replaced by another class. Yet, it is not listed in the [API](https://qgis.org/api/annotated.html) page either.

For qgis 2 code to set layer visibility [as follows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119280):

```
ml = QgsMapCanvasLayer(lyr)
ml.setVisible(False)
```

Does it require certain `import`S in QGIS3 or should it be replaced by something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just for the record, I had to turn to a different class and member function to set the visibility of a layer `lyr` in QGIS 3:

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(lyr.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```

This is based on searching/researching [the breaking change page](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html):

> QgsLayerTreeGroup
>
> setVisible() is replaced by
>   QgsLayerTreeNode::setItemVisibilityChecked()

There might be other ways, but this is what worked for me.

Comment: the 'lyr' part doesn't work in a loop. Any idea why? Trying to toggle visibility to select while rendering and saving as *.png

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is right and I simply want to mention that we can toggle on and off all the layers by:

```
bool = True # or False
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
allLayers = root.layerOrder()
for layer in allLayers:
    root.findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

new_dialog = QDialog()
new_dialog.resize(800, 600)

map_canvas = QgsMapCanvas(new_dialog)
map_canvas.setMinimumSize(800, 600)

layers =  QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
map_canvas_layer_list = [l for l in layers.values()]
map_canvas.setLayers(map_canvas_layer_list)
map_canvas.setExtent(iface.mapCanvas().extent())

new_dialog.show()
```

If read the api break documentation,you can see that you need call `setLayers()` in a `QgsMapCanvas`class.

based in [this](https://github.com/webgeodatavore/pyqgis-samples/blob/master/gui/qgis-sample-QgsMapCanvas.py) sample for QGIS 2

regards