# Uncheck a layer (visibility) on the legend panel using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to uncheck a layer on the layer panel using PyQGIS such that it is not visible on the project without removing it (like with removeMapLayer).

Comment: Did u search ? I see plenty of question about it on this forum ... [qgis] or [pyqgis] ...

Comment: Yes I did. What I'm looking for is quite simple, just to uncheck the layer from the panel, which is why I say I might have overlooked something. What I find is more advanced stuff like removing buttons, or API action.

Comment: @wyvernaizor - Use something like `layer = iface.activeLayer()`; `iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, False)`

Comment: @Joseph Aha, thank you so much. That definitely pointed me into the right direction. I failed to mention that I am using QGIS 3 so your solution was a bit outdated, but I have edited my post with the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Solution: See Joseph's reply. For QGIS 3 and up, see below:

There's also a similar question that I didn't find because I looked for different keywords, my bad.

[QgsMapCanvasLayer in QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272397/qgsmapcanvaslayer-in-qgis-3?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(lyr.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```