# Setting layer visibility in standalone QGIS Python script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, layers, vector-layer

I've been writing a standalone Python script that calls QGIS 3 libraries to draw stuff in a QWidget. I'm trying to change the visibility of layers based on a callback, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is an MRE of the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import os.path

from qgis.core import (
    QgsApplication,
    QgsProject,
    QgsVectorLayer,
    QgsWkbTypes,
)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/bin", True)
from qgis.gui import (
    QgsMapCanvas,
)

def main():
    qgs = QgsApplication([],True)
    qgs.initQgis()

    filepath = '/PATH_TO_S57_FILE/S57.000'
    layer = getALayerWithGeometry(filepath)
    print(layer.name())

    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
    canvas.show()

    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
    canvas.setLayers([layer])
    canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())

    layer_tree = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer)
    breakpoint()
    # vis_target = not layer_tree.isVisible()
    # layer_tree.setItemVisibilityChecked(vis_target)

def getALayerWithGeometry(filepath):
    dataLayer = QgsVectorLayer(filepath,'S57 data','ogr')

    subLayer_str = dataLayer.dataProvider().subLayers()
    for (iSubLayer,subLayer_str) in enumerate(subLayer_str):
        subLayerDefs = subLayer_str.replace('!','').split('::')

        id_ = subLayerDefs[0]
        objectAcr = subLayerDefs[1]
        geometryType = subLayerDefs[3]

        composedURI = f'{filepath}|layerid={id_}|geometrytype={geometryType}'
        layer = QgsVectorLayer(composedURI,f'{objectAcr}({geometryType})','ogr')
        if layer.geometryType() not in (QgsWkbTypes.UnknownGeometry,QgsWkbTypes.NullGeometry):
            return layer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then at the breakpoint:

```
vis_target = not layer_tree.isVisible()
layer_tree.setItemVisibilityChecked(vis_target)
```

- This attempts to use `setItemVisibilityChecked()` after a `QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer()` call described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/272547/192985) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/329342/192985).
- Setting layers with `canvas.setLayers()` works, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: You need to set a bridge between the canvas and the layer tree. Read the "Interaction with Canvas" section of https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/01/30/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-3/, which gives you the code to do so. After setting such a connection, you should be able to see the interaction between both components.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!