# Setting layer visibilty in custom QGIS 3.x application (C++ versus Python)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, c++, qgsmapcanvas, layertree

In my QGIS application, I would like to be able to have a QDialog window pop upon clicking a toolbar icon which lists the layers set to the map canvas, and have QCheckBoxes that allow the user to show/hide layers if needed.  I am trying to do so in a C++ application.  I have a Python version which follows the answer given by Denis Rouzaud in the following example: [Setting layer visibility in QGIS Python API?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119280/setting-layer-visibility-in-qgis-python-api)

Here is the custom slot I wrote which follows the API documentation:

```
void layerDisplay::setDisplay(QString &layerName, bool &isChecked)
{
    for ( QgsMapLayer *lay: qm0->layers() ) //qm0 is QgsMapCanvas
    {
        if ( layerName != lay->name() )
        {
            continue;
        } else
        {
            //pj0 is the QgsProject
            QgsLayerTreeNode *root = pj0->instance()->layerTreeRoot()->findLayer(lay->id());
            root->setItemVisibilityCheckedRecursive(isChecked);
            qm0->refresh();
            QList<QgsMapLayer* > lst = root->checkedLayers();

            if ( lst.isEmpty() )
            {
                cout << "Layer " << layerName.toStdString() << " is not checked" << endl;
            } else
            {
                for ( QgsMapLayer *lc: lst )
                {
                    cout << "Layer " << lc->name().toStdString() << " is checked" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and while the standard output tells me the layers have been checked or unchecked, the map canvas does not update; however the Python code works!  If you need to see more code (eg the widget's header and mainwindow slot) I can update this question.

Comment: Did you declare a `QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge` https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge.html ? It role is to sync `QgsMapCanvas` with the`layerTreeRoot`. It may explains why you do not see change on the canvas although you've changed your `checked` state for a layer. You may alternatively use the `setLayers` instead of going through the use of `layerTreeRoot`. Could be wrong as I do not know your complete application requirement(s)

Comment: @ThomasG77 I did not...and this worked!  Well almost.  It zooms out and away from the set center, anyway to prevent that without manually doing so?

Comment: Maybe `setAutoSetupOnFirstLayer(false)` for your `QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge` instance (check default behaviour with `autoSetupOnFirstLayer()`). According to the API doc, "if enabled, will automatically set full canvas extent and destination CRS + map units when first layer(s) are added".

Comment: @ThomasG77 doesn't seem to offset it; I set it to false initially and then re-center and zoom back in to the set center point.  Still working on having the un-checked layers to reappear upon re-checking but progress is progress, thank you.