# Applying setVisible in PyQGIS 3

Tags: layers, pyqgis-3, visibility, qgsvectorlayer

I tried to use this code from the QGIS 2 version in QGIS 3:

```py
li = iface.legendInterface()
li.setLayerVisible(myLayer, False)
```

I found `QgsAnnotation` but can not use it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting layer visibility with PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119280/setting-layer-visibility-with-pyqgis)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In QGIS 3 If you run:

```
iface.legendInterface()
```

you get an `AttributeError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
  exec(code, self.locals)
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgisInterface' object has no attribute 'legendInterface'
```

Look at:
https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html

> QgsLegendInterface was removed. It was replaced by layer tree API
> (QgsLayerTreeNode class and others). Methods that deal with custom
> actions in main window's layer tree context menu were moved to
> QgisInterface: •  addLegendLayerAction() moved to
> QgisInterface::addCustomActionForLayerType()
> • addLegendLayerActionForLayer() moved to
> QgisInterface::addCustomActionForLayer() •    removeLegendLayerAction()
> moved to QgisInterface::removeCustomActionForLayerType()

If you want to hide the layer:

```
 QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(lyr.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```