# Deselecting layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, select, table-of-contents

I can select a layer using:

```
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName( "lyr_name" )[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(lyr)
```

This selects and highlights the layer in the table of contents.

How can I deselect it so that it is no longer highlighted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the blue / grey selection on the layer in the layer tree view, you can do it with the following code :

```py
### your code ###
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName( "world" )[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(lyr)
#################

# get the Qgis layer tree view (QgsLayerTreeView)
lyr_tree = iface.layerTreeView()
# deselect all the layers
lyr_tree.setCurrentLayer(None)
# or faster with
# iface.layerTreeView().setCurrentLayer(None)
```

---

**Links** :

- [PyQGIS QgsLayerTreeView documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsLayerTreeView.html?#qgis.gui.QgsLayerTreeView.setCurrentLayer)

Answer (score 1):

You can do deselect your selected features with the method `removeSelection()` :

```
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("lyr_name")[0]
lyr.removeSelection()
```

You can also use mActionDeselectAll. Take a look at this code : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155726/197233?

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this only affects features, not the layer itself.